# Change Span text according to site's language

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I've set up a wordpress site in my language and I have added a `<span class="class1">TEXT</span>` to the page in a specific position in the code using the "**Real Time Find and Replace**" plugin.
I'm trying now to create a version of the site using **polylang** but I can't change this specific text since it's hardcoded using the plugin.

Is there any way to change this span class text according to site's locale?

Comment: What plugin are you using with this hardcoded text?

Comment: @mikerojas I'm adding the code with this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/real-time-find-and-replace/
Saw the site's source code, and added this span class where I wanted it to be shown.
But with this way, I can't translate it when I change the language with polylang.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I used Wordpress, but at the time they used to define the webpage's language in the HTML tag according to w3 specifications.

```
<html lang="En">
     <body>
         <span lang="En">Hello</span>
         <span lang="Jp">こんにちは</span>
     </body>
</html>
```

It was common to use that tag to target specifical elements. For this example we would hide all elements that were not in that language, while showing the ones that were. In this example pretend the green is shown and the red is hidden.

```
html[lang="En"] span{background: red;}
html[lang="En"] span[lang="En"]{background:green}
html[lang="Jp"] span{background: red;}
html[lang="Jp"] span[lang="Jp"]{background:green;}
```

When the lang in the HTML is defined as "En" all the tags with "En" will be changed to green and the rest will become red.

If you changed the En to Jp then it would be flipped.

Here is a Repl of it: https://replit.com/@DillonBurnett/targetSpanByLanguage#index.html

Try changing `<html lang="En">` to `<html lang="JP">`.

---

Assuming Wordpress still uses the language tag the same way this should work. Otherwise, I know there are a few plugins for language and a plugin for replacing text as well.